# OpenAFS and Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 and Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11

Tags: network, macos

I am the author of [this blogpost](http://blog.encomiabile.it/2014/12/26/openafs-and-mac-os-x-yosemite/) on how to install OpenAFS on MAC OS X Yosemite. After upgrading Yosemite to version 10.10.4, OpenAFS stopped working. It accepts the Kerberos token but it seems unable to connect to the remote server. Can someone help me investigating this issue? I don't know what to do. I also tried to clone the git repo and compile the latest branch (origin/openafs-stable-1_6_x) but it doesn't work.

The only error I can get is:

```
02/07/15 09:11:38.000 kernel[0]: afs: Lost contact with file server xx.xx.xx.xx in cell yy.yy.yy (code -1) (all multi-homed ip addresses down for the server)
```

In the previous version, I would have gotten the same error immediately followed by the opposite (and positive) one:

```
02/07/15 09:11:54.000 kernel[0]: afs: file server xx.xx.xx.xx in cell yy.yy.yy is back up (code 105) (multi-homed address; other same-host interfaces may still be down)
```

Unfortunately, this second message is not happening anymore. Can this be happening because discoveryd is not there anymore in 10.10.4?

**Update**: I have also added to [my blog post](http://blog.encomiabile.it/2014/12/26/openafs-and-mac-os-x-yosemite/) the instructions on how to make it work with Mac OS X El Capitan.

Comment: The problem looks just on my machine. Others manage to run it flawlessly. When I start the afs.rc manually, I get this `franz@dhcp160 ~ % sudo /Library/OpenAFS/Tools/root.client/usr/vice/etc/afs.rc start
Starting OpenAFS
Loading AFS kernel extensions
Starting afsd
afsd: My home cell is 'zh.teralytics.net'
afsd: cacheFiles autotuned to 3125
afsd: Forking rx callback listener.
afsd: Forking rxevent daemon.
afsd: Forking AFSDB lookup handler.` and then it just hangs there forever. I don't know how to debug this further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the story. After spending two days smashing my head against this problem, I was on the phone with my girlfriend and she says "come on, disable the firewall! That's what bugs us in the workplace when something doesn't work".

Well, I did it. And it worked. System's firewall seems to block afsd. Disabling the firewall solved the issue.

Oh by the way, that's my girl.

Answer (score 1):

The firewall blocks traffic from unsigned binaries.  Your File System, Inc. distributes an OpenAFS installer which is signed and includes signed binaries and a signed kernel extension.  You can obtain it from

https://www.your-file-system.com/openafs-client-installer/download

Comment: I tried installing that version of OpenAFS but the problem isn't solved. Probably there is something else blocking it but I don't know how to investigate this.

Answer (score 0):

The firewall issue is one I chased deep into the kernel to debug; The source for the application firewall's socketfw kext is not available, but it will, on some loads of the AFS3-protocol providing kext, for some (but not all) peer endpoints, return spurious EPERM errors. If you disable the firewall, the issue goes away. if you re-enable the firewall the issue does not come back.